# MVC editor templates: use a selectList in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I want to use EditorTemplates to create a view which displays many models forms so I can create them and relation them.

To do that I have created a House_Extended model:

```
public class Extended_House
{
    public Extended_House() {}

    public House House { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
}
```

In my Create.cshtml I have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.House)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Owner)
```

In the Extended_HouseController I want to pass the Cities to be displayed in the House dropdownlist:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Id_City = new SelectList(db.City, "Id_", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

The House.cshtml is in the EditorTemplates file of Extended_HouseView

@model myproject.Models.House --> here's my problem. I cant get the selectList values. How can I get them?

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id_City, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Inmueble.Id_City", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_City)
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can use dropdown lists with editor templates like this?

Comment: I cant understand ur question :\

Comment: My English is so bad :'( Have you worked with many models in the same view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this is what you are looking for: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

btw:

your `Extended_House` class is looking for me like it should be a ViewModel, you know what it is? If not please take a look e.g. here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx - it's the first link that I got about using ViewModels, there may be others but this gives you a pretty good example.

Comment: The dropdownlist has to take the selectlist values from the database and I can do it from the ExtendedHouse controller with a ViewBag. That is OK, but how can I display it when I use an editorFor(model => model.House)? where model is ExtendedHouse? That selectlist is lost. I haven't understood how ViewModels can help me with my Create action here after reading the article.

Comment: I am glad that I could be any help to you. Good luck!:)